# How to find forks in Activity Java code?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity

I have copy-pasted together MainActivity class for a simple Android application, which uses BluetoothAdapter, TextToSpeech, and also Runnable status checker, running periodically. For the latter, I have "implemented TextToSpeech.OnInitListener".

The code is probably too large to post here, so I will try to formulate the question in general form and then explain why.

How one is supposed to understand where "thread forks" happen in the Java code where everything looks like method invocations? Are there any conventions (for Android libraries specifically, of maybe it's Java-wide) to distinguish simple call from a call, which forks it's own thread? Or is the RTFM the only way to find where forking is happening?

And the actual problem is that Bluetooth LE scanning (?) sometimes duplicates, producing double (or triple, sometimes more) log entries one after another. I guess, I have a mistake somewhere in onStop, onResume, onDestroy, etc hooks (though I was trying to follow state transitions as on the diagram [in the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)), but it is hard to find out why some threads/tasks survive and duplicate.

I am "programming" in Java only occasionally, so I have very little idea how concurrency could be debugged. But may be folks with experience can share general hints/advices/guidelines, useful in much more cases than mine.